# Could not find package gdebi

Tags: 16.04, software-center, gdebi

It seems like a lot of folks have had problems installing 3rd party software with the Software Center.  The usual suggestion is to install and use `gdebi` instead.  However, when I try to do that I get an error:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
E: could not find package gdebi
```

I'm running a new installation of 16.04 LTS desktop installed on a USB drive.

So how do I work around this?

Comment: Did you enable the `universe` repository?

Comment: Try changing the Ubuntu download server to a different country. The current server may be down

Comment: Not familiar with the different repositories or apt in general.  In previous forays into Ubuntu I could get 99% of what I wanted from Software Center and the other 1% was apt-get install that worked first time.  I will research and post update.  

BTW, the accepted answer below works as far as installing gdebi.  Just wish the Software app would work.

Comment: Well, sometimes you actually do get what you wish for!  I don't know how or why but after installing gdebi, Ubuntu Software works.  Yeah!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

Note that in general you can search for packages using:

```
apt-cache search <search_term>
```

So for example:

```
apt-cache search gdebi
```

returns info on the `gdebi-core`, `gdebi` (GNOME GUI), and `gdebi-kde` (KDE GUI) packages.